# How to assign more then one open action to one file system

Tags: windows

All operating system I use apart form Windows have a “Open with…” options for there Explorer, Finder, whatever. This is very useful as often more then one program can handle a given file extension.

With the exception on zip file I generally have not seen such a function on Window. However since there is an exceptions it is possible.

The questions I have is: How can a “Open with…” can be archived with windows? Is there perhaps a tool which can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shift + right-click on the file

Comment: Cool. How could I have missed that? Sadly GIMP is missing from `.PNG` so I still need to know how to add an additional application to the list.

Comment: "Open with" and then "Choose Program" and select GIMP.exe, you can then set GIMP as Default or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems the embarrassing truth is that I missed the “Open with…” which is located in the middle of right-click menu. Great Usability. Most OSs have it right underneath the “Open” option.

Once found the rest was easy to figure out by myself. To add an additional app you use the “Set default application”. In there is an option to add another application which then becomes the new default application.

If you don't want the new application to be the default after all you go into the “Set default application” a 2nd time to change it back.